# Getting a random element in array by a generic function

Tags: swift

```
func ramElment<X, T: CollectionType >(list: T) -> X {
    let len = UInt32(list.count)
    let element = arc4random_uniform(len)
    return list[element]
}
```

it pops up:

error: cannot invoke initializer for type `UInt32` with an argument list of type '(`T.Index.Distance`)'

```
let len = UInt32(list.count)
```

I have checked the `T.Index.Distance` is Int type. but why can't i change the type to `UInt32`?

thanks!

Comment: There are more issues. E.g. you cannot access a `CollectionType` with subscripting so your last line would not work. Are you sure you want a `ConnectionType` as param and not an array?

Comment: @appzYourLife: CollectionType inherits from Indexable, and you *can* access it with subscripting.

Comment: @MartinR: ops... thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Index` of a `CollectionType` is
a `ForwardIndexType`:

```
public protocol ForwardIndexType : _Incrementable {
    // ...
    typealias Distance : _SignedIntegerType = Int
    // ...
}
```

This means that the associated type `Distance` must conform to  `_SignedIntegerType`, and (by default) is `Int` *unless* declared  (or inferred)
otherwise.

*Example:* The following is a valid type conforming to `ForwardIndexType`,
with `Distance == Int16`:

```
struct MyIndex : ForwardIndexType {
    var value : Int16

    func advancedBy(n: Int16) -> MyIndex {
        return MyIndex(value: value + n)
    }
    func distanceTo(end: MyIndex) -> Int16 {
        return end.value - value
    }
    func successor() -> MyIndex {
        return MyIndex(value: value + 1)
    }
}

func ==(lhs : MyIndex, rhs : MyIndex) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

And here is a (for demonstration purposes, otherwise pretty useless)
type conforming to `CollectionType` with `Index == MyIndex`,
`Index.Distance == Int16`:

```
struct MyCollectionType : CollectionType {

    var startIndex : MyIndex { return MyIndex(value: 0) }
    var endIndex : MyIndex { return MyIndex(value: 3) }

    subscript(position : MyIndex) -> String {
        return "I am element #\(position.value)"
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let coll = MyCollectionType()
for elem in coll {
    print(elem)
}
/*
I am element #0
I am element #1
I am element #2
*/
```

But we can also define a forward index type without declaring
any `Distance` type, and using the default protocol implementations
for `advancedBy()` and `distanceTo()`:

```
struct MyOtherIndex : ForwardIndexType {
    var value : Int16

    func successor() -> MyOtherIndex {
        return MyOtherIndex(value: value + 1)
    }
}

func ==(lhs : MyOtherIndex, rhs : MyOtherIndex) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

Now `MyOtherIndex.Distance == Int` because that is the default type
as defined in `ForwardIndexType`.

---

**So how does this apply to your function?**

You cannot assume that
`Index.Distance` is `Int` for an arbitrary collection.

You can *restrict* the function to collection types with
`Index.Distance == Int`:

```
func randomElement<T: CollectionType where T.Index.Distance == Int>(list: T)
```

But you can also utilize that `_SignedIntegerType` can be converted to and from `IntMax`:

```
func randomElement<T: CollectionType>(list: T) -> T.Generator.Element {
    let len = UInt32(list.count.toIntMax())
    let element = IntMax(arc4random_uniform(len))
    return list[list.startIndex.advancedBy(T.Index.Distance(element))]
}
```

Note also that the return type is determined as `T.Generator.Element`,
and cannot be an arbitrary generic type `X`.

This function works with arbitrary collections, for example `Array`, `ArraySlice`, or `String.CharacterView`:

```
let array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
let elem1 = randomElement([1, 2, 3])

let slice = array[2 ... 3]
let elem2 = randomElement(slice)

let randomChar = randomElement("abc".characters)
```

but also with the above custom collection type:

```
let mc = MyCollectionType()
let r = randomElement(mc)
```

Comment: Well... much better than my answer :)

Comment: Sorry! I still don't understand the first part. "The Index.Distance of a CollectionType is not necessarily Int. (It is Int for all concrete collection types that I know of, but the CollectionType protocol definition does not demand that.)

Therefore you can restrict the function to all collection types for which Index.Distance == Int:

func randomElement<T: CollectionType where T.Index.Distance == Int>(list: T) "

Comment: Any type conforms to CollectionType that has an assiocated type "Index". Any type assiocate with "Index" need to conform to "ForwardIndexType" type, the assiocated type "Distance" in "ForwardIndexType" protocol is Int, so other type conforms Collection also conforms to "ForwardIndexType", right? I know I am wrong. But I don't get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3762515: Good point! The *default type* for ForwardIndexType is Int,  the protocol only demands that it is a _SignedIntegerType. – See update!

Comment: The default type for the Distance is Int. Do you mean Int can be ignored? Sorry. I am too stupid.

Comment: And I still don't understand first part: "The Index.Distance of a CollectionType is not necessarily Int. (It is Int for all concrete collection types that I know of, but the CollectionType protocol definition does not demand that.)

Therefore you can restrict the function to all collection types for which Index.Distance == Int:

func randomElement<T: CollectionType where T.Index.Distance == Int>(list: T) "

Comment: @user3762515: `typealias Distance : _SignedIntegerType = Int` means that  the default type for `Distance` is `Int`. So you can define a `struct MyIndex : ForwardIndexType { ... }`, and if you don't define `MyIndex.Distance` explicitly (and if it cannot be inferred from the context) then `MyIndex.Distance` will be `Int`. But you *can*  define a `ForwardIndexType` with `MyIndex.Distance == Int16`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought "= Int" meant anything must be Int. I didn't know it is just a default type. And can be changed when I define a class or struct.

Comment: @user3762515: You are welcome. Actually that was more interesting than I thought initially, and I learned something myself. I have rewritten the answer to (hopefully) be more clear and to address your questions.

Comment: Do you know any website that teaches swift's generic programming? I downloaded the ebook from apple's website that doesn't really specify generic programming. Thank you.

Comment: @user3762515: Unfortunately, I do not have any recommendations.

Comment: How to implement those default methods that take Deflaut type "Int"? I try to look into it, but can't find. Thanks!

Comment: @user3762515: I provided an example (MyOtherIndex) for a forward index type which uses the default Distance type Int. – I don't want to sound rude, but I have really tried to answer your original question and all the additional questions in the comments, as good as I can. If you have additional questions then I would suggest that you post that as a new question.

Comment: You are not rude. You are too nice too me. I feel so bad that keeps asking question. I tried to experiment. But I can't make it. Anyways, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In the title of your question you talk about `Array`. But in your code you are declaring the input param as a `CollectionType`.

If you really want to receive a **Generic Array** param then this is the code

```
func randomElement<T>(list: [T]) -> T {
    let len = UInt32(list.count)
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(len))
    return list[random]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my stupid question. I am new in programming and swift. Very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example what you want.

```
extension CollectionType where Index.Distance == Int {
    func randomElement() -> Self.Generator.Element {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
        return self[startIndex.advancedBy(randomIndex)]
    }
}
```